# Error while converting Timespan with 1 day to Datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, timestamp

I have an application where i show Flight Departure Date and Arrival Date and Flight Time Duration.

For Flight Time Duration , i simply subtract dates which gives me TimeStamp like

```
TimeStamp duration = arrivalDate.subtract(departureDate);
```

so record is like

```
               Departure          Arrival                   Duration
               Sat 07:05A         Sat 09:20A                2h 15m
               Sat 10:10A         Sat 11:15A                1h 05m
               Sat 05:15P         Sat 07:16P                2h 01m
Total Duration                                              5h 21m
```

I have many such flight records and i need to show Total Flight Duration , for this
i simply add Time span like

```
TimeStamp totalDuration = totalDuration.Add(duration);
```

But i got a situation where totalDuration reaches a value like {1.02:10:00} and when trying to convert this value to DateTime like this

```
TotalConnectionTime = new DateTime(2012,06, 30,(int)totalDuration.TotalHours, totalDuration.Minutes, 0);
```

it gives error

**"Hour, Minute, and Second parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."**

**(int)totalDuration.TotalHours = 26 and this create problem**

I need to covert to {1.02:10:00} to 26h 10m which means 1 Day = 24 hours + 2 hours + 10 min

Hope i clear my point.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Anil - can you explain more clearly for me whether this is just a sting representation that you are after or not. there are overrides on TimeSpan which will return 1 day 2 hrs as 26hrs {26:00:00}, so not certain what you've tried in this respect.

Comment: i need to covert this time stamp to DateTime to store in DB so that i can get it for further calculation and also need to use it as string 26h 10m

Comment: Take @jimtollan's advice . A TimeSpan is not a DateTime. You can add a timespan to a date ro give say an expected arrival time. Just converting one is well iffy.

Comment: Store it as a Duration in the db. Say number of seconds or perhaps minutes.

Comment: Anil - go with the advice above given by myself and supported by Tony. store the duration only as an integer (be that seconds or minutes) and also store a UTC of the departure time, then do the maths as required on top.

Comment: @jim , i followed your and Tony advice, and save Duration as minutes in DB, now i have 1570 minutes in DB , now how to convert this to 26h 10 m? i m using this TimeStamp totalTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(grp.LastOrDefault().FlightStat.TotalConnectionTime) then @(totalTime.Hours)h @((int)totalTime.Minutes)m but it gives 2h 10m

Comment: got it i need to use @((int)totalTime.TotalHours)h @((int)totalTime.Minutes)m, thanks alot to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anil,

Bqased on the comments above, I'd suggest saving a DateTime as the Departutre time (UTC) and then saving the minutes as an integer column. You can then calculate the offset as required. Below is a little console app to demonstrate the timespan usage, based on your example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,1570,0);
        var stringDisplay = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", timeSpan.Days, timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes);
        Console.WriteLine(stringDisplay);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

this produces a result of : 1:2:10 (1 day, 2 hours and 10 minutes).

this should work well for you when adding to your initial Departure time, i.e.:

```
DateTime departure = new DateTime(2012, 6, 21, 7, 30, 0);
DateTime completeJourney = departure.Add(timeSpan);
```

Hope this helps.